# Does my choice of parametrization matter in vectors?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, parametric

Let's say I want to know the vector function that represents the intersection of the two surfaces for a cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ and $z=xy$

Would it be alright for me to declare that $x=\sin(t)$ and not $x=\cos(t)$?
I had this question because my textbook always assumes the latter and not the former. Furthermore, I was also wondering if it would be alright for me to arbitrarily declare $x=t$ and continue deducing what the other variables' parameterization could be?

*edit

I meant to say $2\sin(t)$ and $2\cos(t)=x$

Comment: Your choice of parametrization does not matter. I think you probably want to let $x=2\sin t$ instead of $\sin t$ since your cylinder has radius $2$.

Comment: @mvpq oh right forgot about the 2

Comment: For that matter, you could use a rational parameterization of the ellipse instead. It all depends on what you’re going to do with this parameterization. Remember, though, that orientation might matter, e.g., if you’re going to integrate over this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose whichever parameterization you'd like, but it's important to then keep in mind the direction.
Notice that under the `standard' parameterization $x = 2\cos(t), y =2\sin(t)$ you travel around the circle counter-clockwise (between $t = 0, \pi/2$ you travel from $(2,0)$ to $(0,2)$); however, under your parameterization $x = 2\sin(t), y = 2\cos(t)$ when $t = 0$ you start at $(0,2)$ and the proceed clockwise around the circle.

This is not inherently a problem, but occasionally things can differ slightly.

e.g. The helix $x = \sin(t), y = \cos(t), z = t$ is actually distinct from $x = \cos(t), y=\sin(t), z =t$.
(Look at the intersection with the $xy$-plane.)